# Shuffling around elements in a list

Tags: r

My general question concerns shuffling elements around in a list efficiently.

Say I have a list:

```
region <- list(c(1,3,2,6),c(5,8,9),c(10,4,7))
```

and two constants:

```
value <- 2
swapin <- 5
```

I want to do two things.  I want to remove the element == value from the vector in the list, and then add it to the vector in which the first element of that vector == swapin

The result should look like:

```
region <- list(c(1,3,6),c(5,8,9,2),c(10,4,7))
```

For the first step, the only way I can think of doing it is doing something like this:

```
region <- lapply(1:length(region), function(x) region[[x]][region[[x]] != value])
```

but this seems inefficient.  My actual data could involve a very large list, and this approach seems cumbersome.  Is there an easy trick to avoiding the looping going on?

For the second step, I can create an updated vector like this:

```
updated <- c(unlist(region[sapply(region, `[`, 1)==swap]),best)
```

but I am stumped on how to replace the vector currently in the list, c(5,8,9), with the updated vector, c(5,8,9,2).  Maybe I can just add the element some easier way?

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: is it reasonable to assume that `value` and `swapin` are unique in `region`?

Comment: @useR Yes, both are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
region <- list(c(1,3,2,6),c(5,8,9),c(10,4,7))

value <- 2
swapin <- 5

step1 = lapply(region, function(x) x[x != value])

step2 = lapply(step1, function(x){
  if(x[1]==swapin){
    return(c(x, value))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
})
```

Instead of looping through `region` by feeding in it's element indices, you can just loop through `region` itself. This is actually how `lapply` is intended to be used - to apply a function to each element of a list. The second step replaces each element `x`, with `x` + `value` if the first element of `x` matches with `swapin`, or with `x` itself if `swapin` doesn't match.

**Result:**

```
> step2
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 6

[[2]]
[1] 5 8 9 2

[[3]]
[1] 10  4  7
```

You can also easily make it a convenience function for later use:

```
element_swap = function(list, value, swapin){

  step1 = lapply(list, function(x) x[x != value])

  step2 = lapply(step1, function(x){
    if(x[1]==swapin){
      return(c(x, value))
    } else {
      return(x)
    }
  })

  return(step2)

}
```

**Result:**

```
> element_swap(region, 1, 10)
[[1]]
[1] 3 2 6

[[2]]
[1] 5 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 10  4  7  1
```

Comment: Great!  Requires minor edit in step1 where '2' replaced with constant name (value)

Comment: @Nyiannos Good catch. I've also made it a function so you can easily apply different `value` and `swapin` to different lists.